# Must one unsubscribe to an event as a delegate?

Tags: c#, events

I want to do use this little context menu when User presses a button:

```
private ContextMenuStrip TaskMenu()
{
    ContextMenuStrip Result = new ContextMenuStrip();
    Result.Items.Add("Select task to start:");
    Result.Items.AddRange(
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Settings\\Tasks", true), "*.tsk")
            .Select(qF => new ToolStripMenuItem(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(qF)) { Tag = qF, Checked = qF == this.TaskFile })
            .ToArray());
    Result.Items.Add("Cancel");
    Result.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(
        delegate(object s, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs ev) { StartScan((string)ev.ClickedItem.Tag); });
    return Result;
}
```

But, I shouldn't because I never unsubscribe the event.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue here. `Result` is created inside the method, so there is no possibility of attaching the same event handler twice.

When the last reference to `Result` goes out of scope it becomes eligible for garbage collection. As long as nothing outside this method keeps a permanent reference to `Result`, when garbage is collected both it and the reference to the delegate will be cleaned up.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  I am cautious of events; one bit me one time.

Answer (score 0):

> I shouldn't because I never unsubscribe the event, Right?

If you need your event to be unhooked at some point, then this isn't the correct approach. The way around this is to take a reference to the handler so you can unsubscribe it later.

If you are worried purely from a memory leak point of view, then don't. When your `ContextMenuStrip` is GC'd so will your delegate.